# ionic capacitor in app purchase requires to open app to confirm subscription

Tags: android, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase, capacitor

I have used https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase with my ionic capacitor app. i am trying to implement subscription for android. Everything seems to work and subscription can be done from android app. However, when the user goes to play store --> subscriptions they see a message that they should open the app and confirm else the subscription will be cancelled in 3 days.

how do i avoid this requirement? below is my code

```
constructor(public dataSvc: DataService,
      public plt: Platform) {

    if(this.plt !== undefined){

      this.plt.ready().then(() => {
        const store: CdvPurchase.Store = new window.CdvPurchase.Store(); 
        this.registerFunction()
  
        const activeSubscription = store.verifiedPurchases.find(purchase => {
          const product = store.get(purchase.id, purchase.platform);
          console.log("Found purchase at:", product)
          return product?.type === CdvPurchase.ProductType.PAID_SUBSCRIPTION && product.owned;
        });
  
        console.log("active subscripntion####", JSON.stringify(activeSubscription))
      });
    }
   
  }

  registerFunction() {
    const { store, ProductType, Platform, AppleAppStore } = CdvPurchase;
    store.verbosity = 4; //to debug
    
    store.register([
      {
        id: PRODUCT_PRO_KEY,
        type: CdvPurchase.ProductType.PAID_SUBSCRIPTION,

        platform: Platform.GOOGLE_PLAY,
      },
       {
      id: 'test-subscription',
      type: CdvPurchase.ProductType.PAID_SUBSCRIPTION,
      platform: Platform.TEST
       }
    ]);

    store.when()
    .productUpdated((product) =>{
      console.log("The product in new way is:", JSON.stringify(product))
      if(product?.getOffer()?.canPurchase === true){
        this.products.push({
          "title": product.title,
          "price": product.pricing?.price,
          "currency": product.pricing?.currency
        })
      }
    })
    .approved(transaction => {
      console.log("txn approved.", JSON.stringify(transaction))
      transaction.verify()
    })
    .verified((receipt) => {
      console.log("transaction is verified", receipt)
      receipt.finish();
    })
    

      if (this.plt.is('ios')) {
        console.log('init apple');
        store.initialize([{ platform: Platform.APPLE_APPSTORE }]);
      } else if (this.plt.is('android')) {
        console.log('init google');
        store.initialize([{ platform: Platform.GOOGLE_PLAY }]);
      } else {
        console.log('not mobile');
        store.initialize([{platform: Platform.TEST}])
      }
  }//end constructor


  /**
   * Make a purchase
   * @param productId 
   */
  purchase(productId:any){
    console.log("start of product purchase")
    const { store } = CdvPurchase;
    store.get(PRODUCT_PRO_KEY)?.getOffer()?.order();
  }
```